# What is meant by reflection in the lines through $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is from Nathan Jacobson's Basic algebra I:

[image]

These are examples of groups, but in 10. , I can't understand what is meant by 'reflections in the lines through $0$'

Answer (score 1):

Pick a line that goes through the origin. Mirror the whole plane through that line.

For instance, if the line is the $x$-axis, the corresponding reflection is $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$, and if the line is $x=y$, then the reflection is $(x, y)\mapsto (y, x)$.

Comment: In 10, $\theta$ is angle between the 'mirror' (that passes through origin) and x axis? ie, for $x=y$, $\theta=45 degree$?

Comment: @Silent Yes, that's what it is.

Comment: @Silent These groups, that are made up of rotations and mirrorings are called _dihedral_ groups. For instance, if you only allow $90^\circ$ or $180^\circ$ rotations, and only mirrorings through the $x$-axis, the $y$ axis or the two $45^\circ$ lines $x = \pm y$, then what you get is the symmetry group of the square, which usually denoted $D_8$, the dihedral group of eight elements. Some authors use $D_4$ for this group instead, which may lead to confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information!! It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Arthur, sorry to bother you, but if $(x,y)=(1,0)$ then the given equation for reflection in 10 for $\theta=45^ \circ$ takes us to $(\cos 45^\circ,\sin 45^\circ)$, and not to $(0,1)$

Comment: @Silent Oh, you're right. Let's see... If $\theta=90^\circ$, we get $(1,0)\mapsto (0,1)$, and if $\theta=180^\circ$, then $(1,0)\mapsto (-1,0)$. It seems $\theta$ rather represents where the $x$-axis lands. In other words, the mirror stands at $\theta/2$.